# Point Cloud Stitching real time

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to stitch two point cloud inputs from real sense D415 cameras, with overlap real time. I am facing issues with two aspects,

1. Duplicate points also being added - The points which overlap seem to be added twice, despite my best attempts at receiving a transformation matrix, so is there any way I can check and remove the points to make sure it is added only once?[image: Double points at the overlap regions]
2. I need an ordered point cloud to further process the stitched point cloud, but I can't seem to get a proper ordered point cloud [the resize of Final in the code is my attempt to make it ordered]. Any ideas/suggestions to make sure the final point cloud is ordered?

Here is code that I am using currently:

```
void PointCloudMergerNodelet::pc_merge()
{

  // PCL Pointclouds and components declaration and initialization
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_in(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud2_in(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr Align_output(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr Final(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

  std::vector<int> ind1;
  std::vector<int> ind2;
  // Transforming Point Cloud 1 to base frame
  if (sub1_flag == true)
  {
    if (!(target_frame_ == c1_msg->header.frame_id))
    {
      try
      {
        tf2_->transform(*c1_msg, *cloud1RW_, target_frame_,
                        ros::Duration(tolerance_));
        cloud1RW_->header.frame_id = target_frame_;
      }
      catch (tf2::TransformException &ex)
      {
        NODELET_ERROR_STREAM("Transform cloud 1 failure: " << ex.what());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      *cloud1RW_ = *c1_msg;
    }
    pcl::fromROSMsg( *cloud1RW_, *cloud_in );      
  }

  
  // Transforming Point Cloud 2 to base frame
  if (sub2_flag == true)
  {
    if (!(target_frame_ == c2_msg->header.frame_id))
    {
      try
      {
        tf2_->transform(*c2_msg, *cloud2RW_, target_frame_,
                        ros::Duration(tolerance_));
        // tf2_->transform(*c2_msg, *cloud2RW_, target_frame_,
                        // ros::Duration(tolerance_));    
        cloud2RW_->header.frame_id = target_frame_;
      }
      catch (tf2::TransformException &ex)
      {
        NODELET_ERROR_STREAM("Transform cloud2 failure: " << ex.what());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      *cloud2RW_ = *c2_msg;
    }
    pcl::fromROSMsg( *cloud2RW_, *cloud2_in );
  }


  if (cloud1RW_ != 0 && cloud2RW_ != 0)
  {

       // Transformation matrix for cloud 2 to align with cloud 1 (obtained via PCL ICP)
      static Eigen::Matrix4f transformationMatrix = (Eigen::Matrix4f() << 0.999949,0.0058447,0.00823151,-0.0132738,-0.00563437,0.999663,-0.025349,0.360606,-0.0083768,0.0253014,0.999645,0.0215044,0,0,0,1).finished();
      pcl::transformPointCloud( *cloud2_in, *cloud2_in, transformationMatrix);

      if ((cloud1RW_->width != 0) && (cloud2RW_->width != 0))
      { 
        // Adding the two clouds
        *Final=*cloud_in + *cloud2_in;

        //   Resizing the final cloud and assigning properties
        if (cloud_in->height > cloud2_in->height)
        {
          Final->height = cloud_in->height;
        }
        else
        {
          Final->height = cloud2_in->height;
        }
        Final->width = cloud_in->width + cloud2_in->width;
        Final->points.resize(Final->width * Final->height);

        pcl::toROSMsg(*Final, output_);
        NODELET_INFO("Final height %d", output_.height);
        output_.header.frame_id = target_frame_;
        output_.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        output_.is_bigendian = cloud1RW_->is_bigendian;
        output_.is_dense = true;  // there may be invalid points
      }
  }
  NODELET_INFO("FFFF Output Final height %d",output_.height);
  pub_.publish(output_);
  // NODELET_INFO("******** Output Published");
  sub1_flag = false;
  sub2_flag = false;
}
```

I have tried Voxel down sampling, based on suggestions, to remove the duplicate points, it does not fit my use case.

Comment: Are you combining two point clouds from the same camera location at different times, or stereo cameras?  You're sampling a surface, so if the relative displacement from camera to surface changes, you'll get different points after a corrective transform, even though there is just one surface.  And that's before accounting for noise in the measurements.

Comment: Two different stereo cameras, mounted in a static arrangement, on a moving robot. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to overcome that?